# Length of horizontal footnote separator

Tags: footnotes, rules, lengths

I need to reduce the length of the horizontal line that separates text body from footnotes. I am a beginner, using report document class.

Comment: Probably not duplicate, as 21913 provides coding for footnote separator width as thickness or height, not length of the line, which is what I need.

Comment: @Nhaps `width` is nothing but the length. In `\hrule width 0.2\textwidth height 0.4pt` change `0.2\textwidth` and see the difference.

Comment: I finally got this right.